# Docker service needs to affect both replicas of another service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scrapy

Good morning,

I have an issue that I am struggling to diagnose and fix. First a disclaimer I just started learning Python about 6 or 7 months ago and I have no development experience before that. My first project was a web scraping project using the Scrapy engine. After learning Docker I decided I wanted to break it up into containers. That took a bit to figure out but once I did I got it working and coordinated in a docker-compose.yml.

I have 5 services one for Scrapyd which is the daemon/server that the Scrapy engine runs on, one for postgres to collect the scraped entries, one to poll postgres looking for keywords and a postgres service to go with it . Lastly I have the deploy service which is what is giving me trouble.

The deploy service waits for the Scrapyd service to be completely up (verified via a APi call from a script) and then builds python egg files for all my spiders (web crawlers that scrape the data) and sends them via post request to Scrapyd. This all works fine doing my normal compose however now I am trying to deploy this onto a Docker Swarm.

I have my swarm setup on 2 Raspberry Pi's I deploy the Scrapyd service with

```
sudo docker service create --name scrapyd --network scrapy-bridge \
--publish 6800:6800 --hostname scrapyd --with-registry-auth \
--replicas 2 my-registry:test-scrapyd-arm
```

Then I start the deploy service with :

```
sudo docker service create --name scrapyd-deploy --replicas 2 \
--network scrapy-bridge --with-registry-auth \
my-registry:test-scrapyd-deploy-arm
```

All seems to go well except the deploy service only seems to affect one of the replicas of Scrapyd. As I was testing by sending multiple requests for running spiders some would go through and some would return an error that the spider doesn't exist.

I then did :

```
curl 127.0.0.1:6800
```

multiple times and figured out that the spiders were only deployed to one of the Scrapyd replicas

How can I set this up so my deploy service affects the Scrapyd service on both nodes?

docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    scrapyd:
        image: my-image:test-scrapyd
        ports:
            - "6800:6800"
        expose:
            - "6800"
        volumes:
            - Vscrapyd:/app/clist/
        networks: 
             - scrapyd-postgres
             - scrapy-bridge
            # - bridge

    scrapyd-postgres:
        image: my-image:test-scrapyd-postgres
        ports:
            - "5400:5432"
        depends_on: 
            - scrapyd
        volumes: 
            - Vscrapyd-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
             - scrapyd-postgres
             - notify-bridge

    notify:
        image: my-image:test-notify
        depends_on: 
            - notify-postgres
        volumes: 
            - Vnotify:/projects/notify
        networks: 
             - notify-bridge
             - notif-postgres

    notify-postgres:
        image: my-image:test-notify-postgres
        ports: 
            - "5401:5432"
        depends_on: 
            - scrapyd-postgres
        volumes: 
            - Vnotify-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
             - notif-postgres

    scrapyd-deploy:
        image: my-image:test-scrapyd-deploy
        volumes:
            - VTscrapyd-deploy:/app/clist_deploy/
        networks:
            - scrapy-bridge
        command: ["./entrypoint.sh", "scrapyd", "6800" , "python3", "/app/clist_deploy/deploy.py"]


volumes: 
    Vscrapyd:
        external: false
    Vscrapyd-postgres:
        external: false
    Vnotify:
        external: false
    Vnotify-postgres:
        external: false
    VTscrapyd-deploy:
        external: false
    Vscrapyd-api:
        external: false

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: bridge
    notif-postgres:
        driver: bridge
        external: false
    scrapyd-postgres:
        driver: bridge
        external: false
    notify-bridge:
        driver: bridge
        external: false
    scrapy-bridge:
        driver: bridge
        external: false
```

entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

host="$1"
port="$2"
shift 2
cmd="$@"

python3 scrapy_status.py $host $port

# Retrieves the server response and parses out ok if it exists in response
# if ok then breaks out of loop
# until [ $response = "ok" ]

exec $cmd
```

scrapy_status.py

```python
import subprocess, sys, time


def get_scrapyd_status(host, port):

    try:
        result = subprocess.check_output(["curl",f"http://{host}:{port}/daemonstatus.json"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        return result

def main(host,port):
    count = 0
    while (count < 5):
        r = get_scrapyd_status(host,port)

        print(r)
        try:
            r = "".join(map(chr,r)).split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace('"',"").strip()
        except TypeError:
            pass
        if r == 'ok':
            print('Scrapyd is up!')
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print('Scrapyd not up yet...')
            pass
        count += 1
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.argv and len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit('Only 2 arguments are allowed!')
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        host = sys.argv[1]
        port = sys.argv[2]
        main(host,port)
    else:
        sys.exit('Unknown error ocurred')
```

here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bboykin87/aef4a179c54a6cd7f177177af33348e4) to deploy.py if anyone wants to see it

Comment: Can you add the docker-compose file?

Comment: added docker-compose.yml entrypoint.sh and scrapy_status.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are at a point in this project where you are looking to solidify things into a production deployment. First, if you learned all this in 6 months starting with no software development experience, you have done a fantastic job.

Moving on, there is some history at play with your selection of tools and how they interact. Docker Swarm is part of Docker itself, whereas Docker Compose is external to Docker, and works by interacting with the Docker Engine through the Docker API. Really, Compose is just a Python script. Both tools have a lot of similarity these days, and a lot has been added to both incrementally over the past several years.

The interesting part is when you start considering a third tool: Docker Stack. Stack, like Swarm, is part of Docker. Combined, the 2 tools overlap with Compose in a lot of ways. They can both read the same `docker-compose.yml` files (but Stack requires version 3, while Compose can use older version as well).

One of the main differences between Docker Stack and Docker Compose is that the latter will build new images. Stack wants the images pre-built, and will coordinate the setup process from there. For this reason, Compose is still the best choice for what you have been using it for up to this point: local development and testing, where images are being rebuild over and over as part of the development cycle.

So, what am I getting at here? Since you are starting to think about deploying this project using swarm, it might also be a good time to consider using Docker Stack to help coordinate the deployment. You can use:

```
$ docker stack deploy
```

to deploy the stack to a swarm directly.  First, you need to add a registry service:

```
$ docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000 registry:2
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v2/
```

Since you already have the app built and working with `docker-compose`, build it with that:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
[ wait.... ]
$ docker-compose down
```

Push to the registry:

```
$ docker-compose push
```

and try deploying it to a stack:

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stackdemo
```

[this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/) might help. You should be able to use Stack to control the setup of all replicas in the swarm.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this, I am going through setting this up and I have to install 64 bit os on the raspberry pi's to use docker-compose (when I was running docker-compose before it was on an old laptop running ubuntu server)  so I have a bit of work to do.  Thanks again!